# how to run failed maven test case

Tags: maven, flume

I have a following test case failures for maven build as follow:

```
Failed tests:   
  testDestinationExistsAndSameFileWindows(org.apache.flume.client.avro.TestSpoolingFileLineReader): Platform not recognized
  testIncludePattern(org.apache.flume.client.avro.TestReliableSpoolingFileEventReader): Expected 5 files in working dir
  testIgnorePattern(org.apache.flume.client.avro.TestReliableSpoolingFileEventReader): Expected 5 files in working dir
  testIncludeExcludePatternNoConflict(org.apache.flume.client.avro.TestReliableSpoolingFileEventReader): Expected 5 files in working dir
  testIncludeExcludePatternConflict(org.apache.flume.client.avro.TestReliableSpool

ingFileEventReader): Expected 5 files in working dir

Tests run: 410, Failures: 5, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2
.
.
    [INFO] Apache Flume ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.453 s]
    [INFO] Flume NG SDK ....................................... SUCCESS [  5.688 s]
    [INFO] Flume NG Configuration ............................. SUCCESS [  2.438 s]
    [INFO] Flume Auth ......................................... SUCCESS [  10.654 s]
    [INFO] Flume NG Core ...................................... FAILURE  [  8.792 s]
```

I tried to run only failed testDestinationExistsAndSameFileWindows test case as follow:

mvn test -Dtest=testDestinationExistsAndSameFileWindows
got message as No tests were executed! in log

Can anyone help me with right command to run only failed testcase manualy in maven.

Answer (score 0):

testDestinationExistsAndSameFileWindows  is not a class.
Use the following to that test case:
mvn test -Dtest=org.apache.flume.client.avro.TestSpoolingFileLineReader